# How to convert a boolean to Observable<boolean>? Is this possible?

Tags: typescript

```
public isFunctionAssigned(user: IUser, functionality: string): Observable<boolean> {

    //get list of claims assigned
    let userClaims: IClaim[] = [];

    let functionalities: string[] = [functionality];
    let assignedFunctions: string[] = [];

    this.getUserAssignedFunctions(user, functionalities).subscribe(
        userFunctions => {
            return (!(userFunctions && userFunctions.length > 0));
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Fixed code formatting

Comment: Where is the boolean in your code that you want to make an observable from? Won't `Observable.of(true)` work?